# Specific wordpress directory causing 500 internal server error on nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-500

So I have 2 server blocks configured in nginx. The directories are permissioned and chowned the same and all follders/files have same permissions. On the secondary domain wordpress has been installed just fine but on the primary domain I get a 500 internal server error. I have tried downloading a new copy of their latest version and putting it in place of the files and folders with the same result. I have even tried copying the working sites files and folders to the primary website directory and I get the same error. Only thing that is different is the wp-config files as they have obviously different db credentials. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Oh and error logs dont show anything either. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a high probability that the problem is not inside nginx.

Test your WordPress:

1. Check your `.htaccess` file, may be he is corrupt, or contains invalid rules for new domain.

The `.htaccess` file, if it exists, contains a number of rules that tell the server what to do in certain circumstances. It is commonly used for rewriting URLs or preventing access to your site for malicious intent.
If there is an `.htaccess` file there, make a backup and then delete all the contents within, or the whole file. This may remove some important rules, but if the internal server error was caused by a mistake within the file, this will tell you.

2. Turn on debugging in the wp-config.php file.

```
define( "WP_DEBUG", true );
```

3. Deactivate all plugins and switch themes if you have access to your dashboard.

Comment: 1 n/a. No htaccess 2. Already been enabled 3. NA because this is a fresh install.

Comment: Have any info in nginx error log or apache/php log?

Comment: No but now have white screen of death. Both sites have same permissions and owner/groups etc. Wordpress is in the directory, and not even set up yet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: it will be great if you show nginx and apache/php-fpm configs